# Function that prints string items based on first letter of each item

Tags: python, string, sorting

In Python I am trying to create a function that will print items from a string based on the first letter of each string item.

```
def foods(lst):
    if lst[0][0] == 'A':
        print(lst[0])


foods(['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Yogurt', 'Zucchini', 'Grapes'])
Apples
```

I am not quite sure how to make it so that if you wanted to print only items starting with A->L or L->Z based on your list of string items.

I tried to add more if statements with `lst[0][1]` etc to check against each item but nothing would print.

I also tried to create a statement such as:

```
if [x[0] for x in (lst)] == ['A', 'B', 'C']:
```

but nothing would print as well.

Any help would be much appreciated, I hope I made my problem clear.  Thanks.

Based on some of your guys help and reviewing previous notes I found a more "beginner way" of accomplishing what I was trying to ask;

```
    def foods(lst):
        for char in lst:
            if char[0] > 'N':
                pass
            else:
                print(char)
```

Thank you guys for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Give an example of the input and desired output, your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I know I am missing part of the function that says something like if lst[0][0] < 'L' then print(lst[0]) even though I know you cannot do it that way.  The desired output is the printing of only the string items A-L of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, and ord, to do this:

```
[x for x in lst if ord('A') <= ord(x[0]) < ord('L')]
              # check first letter is between A and L


lst = foods(['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Yogurt', 'Zucchini', 'Grapes'])
print [x for x in lst if ord(A) <= ord(x[0]) < ord(L)]
# ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Grapes']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def food(lst, start, end):
    charLst = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'),ord('D'))]
    if lst[0][0] in charLst:
         print(lst[0])


foods(['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Yogurt', 'Zucchini', 'Grapes'], 'A', 'D')
```

> > Apples Bananas